# JMenu doesn't appear until I minimize or resize the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, minimize, jmenu, jmenubar

I have a GUI with a `JMenuBar`, the problem is that sometimes a `JMenu` doesn't appear until i resize or minimize the `JFrame`. Can someone help me?

Comment: Help use help you by providing us with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: We cannot help you without code that reproduces your problem. Please keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Check your [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) usage, and make `setVisible()` _last_.

Comment: A workaround is to recall `setSize()` as the last method for GUI rendering; the problem is as @trashgod mentioned.

Comment: @m3th0dman  A future bug is to try to solve this by using.. *"recall setSize() as the last method for GUI rendering;"*

Comment: @m3th0dman I think Andrew means its no use to fight a *bug* with a method that may cause a future *bug* as its not considered good practice to call `setSize()` on `JFrame` rather use `LayoutManager`s and call `pack()`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by setting the `JFrame` visible AFTER the code for the menu. So you first create a `JFrame` after that add the `JMenuBar` and at last: `frame.setVisible(true);` (my frame is just called "frame" replace the "frame" with the name of your frame)

Answer (score 2):

Another, less pretty than @Marko's solution, is to call `frame.revalidate()` after the `frame.setJMenuBar()`-call.

Comment: This ends up being better when adding more menu items later on during run-time. Toggling setVisible(...) causes the window to flicker every time something is changed.